# Парсинг HTML в Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Имеется задача каждые 10 минут доставать изображение радара с [pogoda.by](https://pogoda.by/observation/radars/UMBB) и скачивать в папку.
Достать изображение не сложно, это я уже сделал вот так:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     
       URL url = new URL("https://pogoda.by/files/radars/static/33008/Radar_33008_MAP_PHEN_20220528_1440.png");
       InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
       ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       int n = 0;
       while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
       {
          out.write(buf, 0, n);
       }
       out.close();
       in.close();
       byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\RadarMaps\\test_map.png");
       fos.write(response);
       fos.close();
       
    }
}
```

Но, основной проблемой является достать сам **URL** картинки. Для этого пытался использовать Jsoup, но  результатов пока нет :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    
    private static Document getPage() throws IOException {
        String url ="https://pogoda.by/observation/radars/UMBB";
        Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
        return page;
    }
 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
       Document page = getPage();
       Element div = page.select("div[class=view]").first();
       System.out.println(div);   
    }
}
```

HTML код сайта:

```
<app-view _nghost-serverapp-c6="" style="height: calc((100vh - 71px) - 49px); padding-top: 0px; display: block;">
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="wrapper-radar">
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="container-radar" style="min-height: calc(100% - 858px);">
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="section">
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="main-column">
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6=""><div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="player">
<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" class="view">
<img _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" src="//pogoda.by/files/radars/static/33008/Radar_33008_MAP_PHEN_20220529_0610.png">
</div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </app-view>
```

Comment: Что значит `результатов пока нет`? Попробуйте залоггировать (продебажить) что у вас получается и сравнить это с тем что ожидается. Возможно вы не так селектор прописали или сайт вообще js-ом динамически контент грузит. В таком случае вам нужен будет виртуальный браузер, типа Selenium

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вполне вероятно, что селектор неверный, но я не знаю, как его правильно прописать.

Comment: Покажите в вопросе как выглядит HTML код. (все предки нужного элемента, а лишнее стоит убрать, наверняка там много кода). Я сам в селекторы не умею, но без них - знаю как)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил.

Comment: Попытаюсь угадать:) `page.select("div.view")`

Comment: @Sergey, к сожалению ничего не поменялось, по-прежнему `null` =(

Comment: Можно же как-то распечатать page в виде текста. Наверняка видимый html получается динамически, а в исходной странице нет ничего такого, чтобы нам тут показываете. Вы как раз напечатаете исходную страницу и убедитесь, что там ничего нет.

Comment: @Sergey, да, можно. Просто заменить в sysout div на page. И получается, что с динамической подгрузкой такой вариант не прокатит?

Comment: Конечно не прокатит. Нужны средства автоматизации/эмуляции браузера. Хотя недавно довелось познакомится с такими, но уже даже название забыл. Из того, что постоянно на слуху - Selenium. У него, пишут, даже имеется библиотека для java. Предполагаю Selenuim может загрузить страницу, выполнить всё скрипты, и у него можно получить готовую страницу для анализа. Или вообще все работы в selenium-е выполнить.